# Indexable skiplist implementations in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, skip-lists

All of the skip list implementations I have found so far use keys and associate them with values.
But what I need is a skip list, where I can insert a value at an index position i, so that all the values following this
index i can be queried with an index incremented by one.

here a little example for clarification:

```
//pseudocode
//let skipList sk be a list of ints, containing 5 elements.

//insert 6 at index 3
sk.insert(3, 6);

//insert 5 at index 3
sk.insert(3, 5);

//get index 4
int value = sk.get(4);
```

now `value` should be 6, because 5 was inserted at index 3 so the value 6 moved one index up.

it is possible to build a data structure like this using a skip list, see 
Indexable skiplist here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

but i could not find an implementation. it would be very useful to have such a datastructure e.g. in situations where you have many random inserts and accesses on big lists.

Comment: I've never encountered a situation where I'd have many random inserts and random access by index rather than key. And to be honest I can't even imagine one, because the random inserts mean you'll quickly loose track of which index is interesting.

Comment: in situations where array databases could be used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_DBMS. here you have data which is not indexed.

Comment: @JanHudec My favorite type of comment: *I* don’t see how it’s useful and (since I know everything) I declare it’s not useful  What about a circular list by time where you need the median and quartiles by value? How do you maintain two orders on the same list? Think about the rolling history of a currency (a time series.) Think about 1500 currency pairs. Think about 5000 book updates per second on a crypto exchange. You want a market survey with robust stats on all pairs consumed by a realtime trading strategy. How do you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a link to an implementation in the wikipedia page you posted:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576930/

It is python though.

Alternatively, take an existing C++ implementation and add the link widths to it and implement the indexed lookup.

Comment: sorry but this list does not offer the interface i am asking for.

Comment: I thought _ _ getitem _ _ offered the same as 'get' in your example code - i.e. get an item by index?  If not then what are you asking for?

Comment: Actually, yes I do see what you went.  Essentially a sparse vector/list.  I don't think a skiplist is what you are after since it is a key/value store

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not describe a list that offers an insert operation like the way you describe above.

Comment: i think the described list in the wikipedia article could offer such an insert, but you are right they do not mention an insert function. a big vector is very slow, when inserting an element at a random index.

Comment: But, in your example, inserting at position 3 twice would overwrite the element with the key value of 3.  If you need to then go and update all keys for indices following that node afterwards, then you'd need to implement that behaviour and is not what the Wikipedia article is describing.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a skiplist class in C# that has a method which returns the k-th largest value in the collection. It does exactly what you need for your `get` method.

However, the insertion method doesn't specify a position since it always keeps the list sorted therefore the position is determined by a lookup among existing values.

Take a look at https://github.com/htoma/algorithms/blob/master/Algorithms/Algorithms/Sources/SkipLists/SkipList.cs, method `FindKLargestElement`

Comment: https://github.com/htoma/algorithms/blob/master/Algorithms/Algorithms/Sources/SkipLists/SkipList.cs